# Mtk Android13 colour gamut

Tags: android, video

I played a h264 video stream on my Android device and had no problem playing both the full and limit gamut video, as well as a limited and full gamut video stream. However, when playing the bitstream with full gamut and then limited gamut, the second half of the limited video will blink. At present, it can be confirmed that the decoded color gamut information is normal. Do you know what causes it?

Does anyone else have a similar problem.